# SlickGrid javascript get current row data

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I would like to remove a row when I press the Delete key. But I can't get any data from the source below:

```
var selectedrows = grid.getSelectedRows();

grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(function(event) {
    var item = data[selectedrows.cell];
    if (event.keyCode == 46) {
        alert(item.hostname);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `getSelectedRows()` function returns an `Array` of the selected column numbers. The way you are trying will return `undefined`, since that `Array` doesn't contain any property called *cells*.

Open this official SlickGrid [example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example9-row-reordering.html) demo and try the following:

Select the first row in grid.

Try issuing the following command in your JS debugger console:

```
grid.getSelectedRows()
```

Will return you an Array with the selected row number as:

> Array [ 0 ]

The returned `Array's`first element is the row number that you have just selected.

Now that we know the selected row number issue this:

```
data[grid.getSelectedRows()[0]]
```

Will return you the selected `Object` as:

> Object { name: "Make a list", complete: true }

If you want to reach a property of the returned `Object` you could do it as:

```
var selectedRow = data[grid.getSelectedRows()[0]];
console.log(selectedRow.name);
```

Will return the property *name*'s value as:

> Make a list

Hope this clears up your confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It helps.